# Time complexity for an analysis recursive algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, analysis

Any idea what the time complexity could be for this recursive algorithm please?

/* The function f(x) is unimodal over the range [min, max] and can be evaluated in Θ(1) time
 * ε > 0 is the precision of the algorithm, typically ε is very small
 * max > min
 * n = (max - min)/ε, n > 0, where n is the problem size */

```
Algorithm(max, min){
  if ((max - min) < ε){
       return (max - min)/2   // return the answer
 }


 leftThird = (2 * min + max) / 3      // represents the point which is 1/3 of the way from min to max
 rightThird = (min + 2 * max) / 3   // represents the point which is 2/3 of the way from min to max

 if (f(leftThird) < f(rightThird))
 {
       return Algorithm(max,leftThird)   // look for the answer in the interval between leftThird and max
 }
 else
 {
       return Algorithm(min, rightThird)  // look for the answer in the interval between min and rightThird
 }
```

}

Comment: You're missing parts of that code, because what you have is `O(1)` -- and useless.

Comment: hey Blindy, even though the question is aimed to use Master theorem?:

Create a recurrence function to represent the following algorithm's time complexity and use the master method to analyse the above algorithm

Comment: Yes, because there is no recursion in that code. The only function is `Algorithm`, and it doesn't call itself.